# Proof: Characterization of Extreme Points

Tags: convex-analysis

I'm having difficulty following a proof in the book [Nonlinear Programming Theory and Algorithms, Third Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471486000) by Bazaraa, Sherali, and Shetty on page 68 section 2.6.4. The proof is reproduced below, up to the part of the proof I'm confused about.

My question concerns the author's statement:

> But this implies that $x_{11} = x_{21} = B^{-1}b$.

I don't see how the author makes that connection.

**Theorem (Existence of Extreme Points)**

Let $S = \{ x : Ax = b, x \geq 0\}$, where $A$ is an *m x n* matrix and $b$ is an *m*-vector. A point $x$ is an extreme point of $S$ *if and only if* $A$ can be decomposed into $[B, N]$ such that

$x = \begin{bmatrix}
x_B \\ x_N
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
B^{-1}b \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}$

***Proof***:

Suppose that $A$ can be decomposed into $[B, N]$ with $x = \begin{bmatrix} B^{-1}b \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $B^{-1}b \geq 0$. It is obvious that $x \in S$. Now suppose that $x = \lambda x_1 + (1 - \lambda)x_2$ with $x_1$, $x_2 \in S$ for some $\lambda \in (0,1)$. In particular, let $x^{t}_{1} = (x^{t}_{11}, x^{t}_{12})$ and $x^{t}_{2} = (x^{t}_{21}, x^{t}_{22})$. Then

$\begin{bmatrix} B^{-1}b \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \lambda \begin{bmatrix} x_{11} \\ x_{12} \end{bmatrix} + (1 - \lambda) \begin{bmatrix} x_{21} \\ x_{22} \end{bmatrix}$

Since $x_{12}, x_{22} \geq 0$ and $\lambda \in (0,1)$, it follows that $x_{12} = x_{22} = 0$. But this implies that $x_{11} = x_{21} = B^{-1}b$ and hence $x = x_1 = x_2$. This shows that $x$ is an extreme point of $S$.

Comment: First: It's only proper when excerpting a proof (or when quoting or paraphrasing a text) to provide the author's name, the title, edition of the text, page numbers...etc. Second: I'm assuming this is only "half" the proof? (i.e., the proof of "if" portion of Theorem?)

Comment: @Theo: I just submitted an edit of the question, and only afterwards saw your edit.  Sorry if I impacted your edit.

Comment: @Amy: no problem, I had a mathematical objection. Pete L. Clark seems to have approved and slightly improved on your purely linguistic submission, so I just re-introduced my simple corrections.

Comment: @Amy: Thanks Amy, I edited the post to include the author, title, and page number. You are correct in assuming it was only half the proof as I wasn't able to get past that sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $x_1,x_2 \in S$ and hence $Ax_1 = b$ and $Ax_2 = b$. Hence, you get $x_{11} = x_{21} = B^{-1}b$ and hence $x_1 = x_2$.

To elaborate a bit, since $x_{1},x_{2} \geq 0$ and $\lambda \in (0,1)$, we have $x_{12} = 0 = x_{22}$.

Now, $Ax_1 = b \implies Bx_{11} + Nx_{12} = b \implies B x_{11} = b \implies x_{11} = B^{-1}b$.

Similarly, $Ax_2 = b \implies Bx_{21} + Nx_{22} = b \implies B x_{21} = b \implies x_{21} = B^{-1}b$.

Hence, $x_1 = x_2$ and both equals $x$.

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful. I think a big part of my source of confusion was that I forgot that the matrix A was full rank so Ax=b must have only one solution for x.

Comment: @coderdave: I seriously hope that this was a typo in your last comment. What is true is that $B$ is invertible and so $Bx_{B} = b$ exactly one solution among the vectors *whose first $m$ entries* are the only non-zero ones, that's what Sivarams argument rests upon. If what you said was true, the theorem would be rather pointless! Think of the two-dimensional case, e.g. $A = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and draw a picture of $S$! Similarly, draw a picture of $S$ for $A = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and different inhomogeneities $b$.

Comment: @coderdave: sorry, that should have been $A = [1 \;1]$ and $A = [1 \; 1 \; 1]$ in the previous comment.

Comment: @Theo: Thanks, it was a typo but I did what you said and then went through the proof and I have a better understanding of it. It was a lot easier when I worked out examples, I should have done that from the beginning. Thank you for the help.